# Mesh Deform a complex grid with shape key, many problems

Tags: modeling, mesh

I’ve been trying to model a portable cd/radio device similar to the attached photo, with great success up to the point of the speakers. In most devices the speaker is covered with a metallic honeycomb grid. So, I decided not to use clip map and see the result in rendering but use actual geometry.

I’ve modeled a low poly surface (name Grid_orderR, 4k vertices) with shape key to deform the honeycomb grid (name honeycomb, 132k vertices). Object Grid_orderR has a Solidify modifier and object honeycomb has a mesh deform modifier. The problem is that nothing happens unless the thickness in solidify takes a high thickness value 0.3 in blender units. And then the deform has unexpected results because Solidify has overlapping areas due to the high thickness value.
Uploaded file includes the two objects without the deformers.

Any ideas?
[image]

[enter link description here][2]

Blend file for tests [2]: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/40068